# Avoiding empty plots when plotting with chart_Series in an Rhtml (knitr) document

Tags: r, knitr, quantmod

I am using knitr to generate an HTML document with embedded plots. I am having problems when the chart_Series function is placed in a loop. If I specify fig.keep="last", I only get the last plot (out of three). If I choose the option  fig.keep="high", I obtain empty plots preceding the actual plots. A minimal working example is provided below.

```
<!--begin.rcode
opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE) 
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center', fig.keep="high") 
opts_chunk$set(dpi=150) 

library(xts)
library(quantmod)

data(sample_matrix)
s <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
end.rcode-->

<html>

<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>One plot</h1>

<!--begin.rcode
print(chart_Series(s))
end.rcode-->
<h1>Three plots</h1>

<!--begin.rcode
for (i in seq(1:3)) {
  print(chart_Series(s))
}
end.rcode-->
</body>
</html>
```

How do get rid of the "empty" plot at the beginning?

Comment: I might have [fixed](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/commit/be1921c12d554ef5bff0bff2eebfd8a7c402b80f) this problem in the development version of the **evaluate** package; please try `devtools::install_github('hadley/evaluate')`.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comment, this is a bug of the **evaluate** package that has been [fixed](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/commit/be1921c12d554ef5bff0bff2eebfd8a7c402b80f). It will appear in **evaluate** (>= 0.5.7) on CRAN in the future. For now, you can

```
devtools::install_github('hadley/evaluate')
```